# refinement panel based on list name?

Tags: 2010, search, refinement-panel

so, here is my scenario
I have 4 lists of links, lets call it internal, external, private, whatever.
Each list has title and link, and each list might be too long, 200 items.

We want the user to search (hopefully OOTB functionality), and find a list item easily.
Please note there might be thousand items that match the keyword the user typed in other libraries, (not in those 4)

I added a content type refinement panel, but the content type for these list is Item. So its useless for this.

I wonder if I can put a refinement category based on the list name but couldnt find a solution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but why not just create a search scope that only includes those 4 lists and add a search webpart and search results webpart to some page with that scope hardcoded?

Answer (score 0):

I'm just starting to research this concept: Adding List to the refinement panel.  Only thing found so far involved FAST:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fastsharepoint/thread/90303236-8790-44cd-b5d6-b9c8db746c5d/

Comment: While the link may have information relevant to the question, it is best to summarize the relevant content in your answer. This helps to future-proof your answers from broken links.